# How to calculate the month begin and end month date from date in polars?

Tags: python, date, python-polars

Is there an efficient way to get the month end date on a date column.  Like if date =‘2023-02-13” to return “2023-02-28”, also beginning of the month would be great as well.
Thanks!

```
df = pl.DataFrame({'DateColumn': ['2022-02-13']})

test_df = df.with_columns([
    pl.col('DateColumn').str.strptime(pl.Date).cast(pl.Date)
]
)

┌────────────┐
│ DateColumn │
│ ---        │
│ date       │
╞════════════╡
│ 2022-02-13 │
└────────────┘
```

Two new columns would be perfect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Update]:** Polars has since added `.month_start()` and `.month_end()` methods.

See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77221887/19355181) from @n-maks

---

You could use [`.truncate`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.dt.truncate.html)
and
[`.offset_by`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.dt.offset_by.html)

```
test_df.with_columns(
   MonthStart = pl.col("DateColumn").dt.truncate("1mo"),
   MonthEnd = pl.col("DateColumn").dt.offset_by("1mo").dt.truncate("1mo").dt.offset_by("-1d")
)
```

```
shape: (1, 3)
┌────────────┬────────────┬────────────┐
│ DateColumn | MonthStart | MonthEnd   │
│ ---        | ---        | ---        │
│ date       | date       | date       │
╞════════════╪════════════╪════════════╡
│ 2022-02-13 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-02-28 │
└────────────┴────────────┴────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a more concise and readable solution using [.dt.month_start()](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.dt.month_start.html) and [.dt.month_end()](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.dt.month_end.html):

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({'DateColumn': ['2022-02-13']})

test_df = df.with_columns([
    pl.col('DateColumn').str.strptime(pl.Date).cast(pl.Date)
])

test_df.with_columns(
   pl.col('DateColumn').dt.month_start().alias('MonthStart'),
   pl.col('DateColumn').dt.month_end().alias('MonthEnd')
)
```

```py
shape: (1, 3)
┌────────────┬────────────┬────────────┐
│ DateColumn ┆ MonthStart ┆ MonthEnd   │
│ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---        │
│ date       ┆ date       ┆ date       │
╞════════════╪════════════╪════════════╡
│ 2022-02-13 ┆ 2022-02-01 ┆ 2022-02-28 │
└────────────┴────────────┴────────────┘
```